# Rail TimeWithZone versus Date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have this method in my model:

```
def date_ranges
  reservations = Reservation.where(["transport_id =?", transport_id])
  reservations = reservations.where(['id <> ?', id]) if !id.nil?
  reservations.map { |e| e.reservation_start..e.reservation_end }
end
```

It is working just fine (thanks to some help from StackOverflow).

My `reservation_start` and `reservation_end` column are of `date` type. Here's my migration:

```
class CreateReservations < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :reservations do |t|
      t.references :user, index: true
      t.references :transport, index: true

      t.date :reservation_start
      t.date :reservation_end
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

If I try to run this method after migrating from `date` column type to `datetime` type I get an error:

```
can't iterate from ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone
```

It won't work even if I change the code in my method to:

```
reservations.map do |e|
  e.reservation_start.to_datetime..e.reservation_end.to_datetime
end
```

Comment: Which Ruby/Rails versions are you using?

Comment: Ruby 2.1.4 and Rails 4.1.5

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the range should have a granularity of at least 1 day if you want to iterate on the DateTime range. Thus, it appears that **the error is in where you're using the `#date_ranges`, and not in the method itself**.

Since you're using the `ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone` (this is the kind of object you get when using `datetime` SQL type), you have something more precise than just date – you have the time also.

So depends on how you use the method.

You have two options to fix this:

1. Change the code to the following:

   ```
    reservations.map do |e|
      e.reservation_start.to_date..e.reservation_end.to_date
    end
   ```

   This way you'll lose time precision, only falling back to dates.
2. Change the way you're using `#date_ranges` method. Probably the best would be to have it returned arrays of `[begin_date, end_date]`.

   ```
    def date_ranges
      Reservation.where(transport_id: transport_id).pluck(:reservation_start, :reservation_end)
    end
   ```

   Depending on how you use the range, you can figure this out:

   - If you're checking if a particular time is within any of given date ranges, you can do this:

     ```
     date_ranges.any? { |date_range| date_range.cover?(my_time) }
     ```
   - If you're displaying the dates:

     ```
     date_ranges.each do |date_range|
       # display the date range
     end
     ```